# OOP fatal error

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong here folks?

```
<?php
include 'header.php';

/**
* Display a user's profile
*/

$id = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$user_res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
$user = $user_res->fetch_assoc();
?>

<h1><?php echo $user['username'] ?>'s Profile</h1>

<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Equals to:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\profile.php on line 12</pre>`

Comment: $db isn't defined as an object, thus PHP doesn't like it. It seems your header.php file doesn't contain the appropriates information about $db.

Comment: Do you actually have any sort of db object, or are you just looking for `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `mysql_query()` and `mysql_fetch_assoc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a variable `$db`, or `$db` is not the database object you expect. You either need to create it first, or it should have been created in `header.php` but wasn't.

Answer (score -1):

In your line

```
$db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

`$db` is supposed to be an object, but apparently it is either nothing or something that's no an object. You need to instantiate (create) the object at some point.

```
$db = new DatabaseObject();
// substitute "DatabaseObject" with the actual name of the Class
```

Did you do that?